# How to sort this according to x in java

Tags: java

I am trying to sort this json object according to "x" but can't find any solution.

```
{
    "resources": [, {
        "urlC": "https://example.com/ghi.png",
        "size": 1657,
        "x": 610026.970856,
        "y": 2,
        "x2": 610026.970874,
        "status": 200
    },{
        "urlC": "https://example.com/abc.png",
        "size": 1827,
        "x": 610026.970777,
        "y": 0,
        "x2": 610026.970795,
        "status": 200
    }, {
        "urlC": "https://example.com/def.png",
        "size": 2026,
        "x": 610026.970816,
        "y": 1,
        "x2": 610026.970835,
        "status": 200
    }, {
        "urlC": "https://example.com/jkl.png",
        "size": 1871,
        "x": 610026.970897,
        "y": 3,
        "x2": 610026.970914,
        "status": 200
    }]
}
```

I want this type of data :

```
{
"resources": [{
    "urlC": "https://example.com/abc.png",
    "size": 1827,
    "x": 610026.970777,
    "y": 0,
    "x2": 610026.970795,
    "status": 200
}, {
    "urlC": "https://example.com/def.png",
    "size": 2026,
    "x": 610026.970816,
    "y": 1,
    "x2": 610026.970835,
    "status": 200
}, {
    "urlC": "https://example.com/ghi.png",
    "size": 1657,
    "x": 610026.970856,
    "y": 2,
    "x2": 610026.970874,
    "status": 200
}, {
    "urlC": "https://example.com/jkl.png",
    "size": 1871,
    "x": 610026.970897,
    "y": 3,
    "x2": 610026.970914,
    "status": 200
}]}
```

Comment: Hint: Use a JSON library.

Comment: I am new in java. I tried but don't get what I need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575757/how-to-sort-gson-array-based-on-a-key

Comment: What problem do you have? You don't know how to parse JSON? You don't know how to use `sort` method? You don't know how to sort on specific field?

Comment: I don't know how to sort on specific fields.

Comment: @amit lodhi Did you refer what Aditya has put the link for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort GSON Array based on a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575757/how-to-sort-gson-array-based-on-a-key)

Comment: Post an [mcve] of what you've tried and what problems you are having with it.

Comment: This post already exists and will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277715/how-to-sort-json-object-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort JSON object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277715/how-to-sort-json-object-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you an alternative way which you can do it by yourself.

Step-1: 
convert the json into java object.

step-2:
then sort the array based on "x" using comparator interface.

step-2:
Again convert java object into json string